# How can I define a variable inside a function only the first time its called?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

I need to define a variable into a function's scope, but only the first time its called. The function will be called multiple times because it's inside a for loop, so defining a variable every time its called would make that variable unusable, since I need it to retain the value I want. I don't want to use a class, because then I would need to create a new instance of the class every time I want to use the function, and I can't use a global variable, because then multiple calls of the function would change that variable at different times and it would just make a mess. Consider this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
    myFunction(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
}
```

The for loop will repeat itself x times, and the function will be called x times too. Now, consider this is the function definition:

```
function myFunction(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3){
    var a = 5;
    var d = 0;

    parameter2[d].method();
    d++;
}
```

(This is a hypothetical situation, the unused parameters and variables should not bother you).

Now, as you can see, I need to go through parameter2's array, but I can't do that when d is constantly being defined to 0 every time its called. I need it to be defined the first time only, and then it can be added to it. As I said, no global variables or classes, they can fix the problem but they are unpractical for my use.

Comment: The only way to accomplish this is declare the variable outside of the function. You can use an `if` statement to check if it's been set and then not updated it if that condition is true.

Comment: I was thinking that there might be something along the lines of a constructor function, like classes have, that would be a godsend.

Comment: @ScottMarcus well a generator function or just function properties would do the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up using a class despite me not wanting to. It's the easiest answer honestly, I have to make a compromise but at least it works. If anyone needs to know how, here's how:

```
class myClass{
    constructor(){
        this.d = 0;
    }

    someMethod(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3){
        this.a = 0;
        parameter2[this.d].method();
        this.d++;
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to use it, you define a variable that contains an object of this class.

```
var someVar = new myClass();
```

Then you can use the variable elsewhere as such:

```
someVar.someMethod(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
```

That's it, I wanted to avoid creating variables each time, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a property on a function, which would probably the most akin to what you want to do

```js
function increaseCaller( args ) {
  let d = increaseCaller.d || 0;
  args[d]( d );
  increaseCaller.d = d + 1;
}

function log( arg ) {
  console.log( 'log: ' + arg );
}

function warn( arg ) {
  console.log( 'warn: ' + arg );
}

function error( arg ) {
  console.log( 'error: ' + arg );
}


const params = [log, warn, error];

increaseCaller( params );
increaseCaller( params );
increaseCaller( params );
```

another option is however, to use [a generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) instead, like

```js
function *methodCaller( args ) {
  let d = 0;
  while (d < args.length ) {
    yield args[d](d);
    d++;
  }
}

function log(arg) {
  console.log('log: ' + arg);
}

function warn(arg) {
  console.log('warn: ' + arg);
}

function error(arg) {
  console.log('error: ' + arg);
}


const params = [log, warn, error];

const iterator = methodCaller( params );

iterator.next();
iterator.next();
iterator.next();
```

Now, this might not be exactly what you are after, however, it does allow you to reset your function,  by simply calling `methodCaller` again with different arguments, and how you want to let it handle the iterations is up to you :)

This does take a bit of getting use to, but these generators are really useful :)

Comment: Yeah, not exactly what I want, I don't really know if what I want is possible but I'll try to fiddle around with it. Thanks.

Comment: @TomásRalph To be honest, the generator function looks like the most likely candidate, as it keeps a nice local scope and it doesn't really interrupt the flow of your program (though you have to use the `.next()` all the time, or use `...iterator()` or `Array.from( iterator )` kind of things :)

Comment: @Icepicke I ended up using a class, then define a new variable that contains an object from the class. Its not ideal, since I would like for it to be only one definition (the function's definition) and not several for each time I wanna use it, but it will do for now.

Comment: @TomásRalph That is interesting considering this was exactly what you didn't want to do :) However, please post it as an answer, so that future people who are looking for an answer might benefit from your extra research :)

Comment: I know it's EXACTLY what I didn't want, however is not something I didn't consider. If there was no easy answer I knew I would probably end up using that. I may change it if I find an alternative.